# Category Hierarchy

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have a category table with just two fields - i.e., `id` and `categoryname` - and a `category_parent` table with fields `categoryid` and `parentid`.  Both are foreign keys for `categoryid`.

So I can have multiple parents or multiple childrens for a category.

My question is: how can I find all the parents or all the childrens of a particular category?

By "all the parents", I mean immediate parents as well as parents of immediate parents and so on. I need IDs of the parents in an array or in a list.

I would prefer a C# code for this problem.

Comment: Which flavor of SQL are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, etc...

Comment: Do you need a simple select statement or a function or store procedure is a solution for you?

Comment: Why do you have a table for `category_parent`? Can a category have multiple parents? If not, it seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Justin Well, actually I am using Mysql but I need all these parents in my C# Code in a array or in a List<int>.

Comment: @arxanas Yes, a category can have multiple parents or multiple childs as I mentioned in the Question.

Answer (score 1):

it's not necessary category_parent.you can do everything about category and parents on a table.

SELECT CatgoryId,CategoryName FROM Category WHERE ParentId is null >>> this is for main categories

SELECT CategoryId, CategoryName FROM Category WHERE ParentId=2 >>> for a specific category

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Category](
[CategoryId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CategoryName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[ParentId] [int]  FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[Category] ([CategoryId]))
```

Comment: How is it possible to have multiple parents or multiple children of a category in your table?

Comment: When you insert data into the table, like that ,



-------------CategoryId - CategoryName - ParentId  (HEADERS) ----                                 

1        -   PC        -  null
2        -   Phone     - null
3        -  Nokia      - 2 (ParentId=2 (Phone))
4        -  Nokia5110  - 3 (ParentId=3 (Nokia))
5        -  Casper     -  1 (ParentId=1 PC)

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use [recursive common table expression](http://publibz.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr_OS390/BOOKS/DSNAPJ10/APPENDIX1.5?DT=20040210163115#TBLWQ1040) 
But I assume MySQL doesn't support this (please correct me if I'm wrong)
So you may want to use cursors or stored procedures. Also read this article on [managing hierarchical data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Comment: Actually what I need is a c# code so that I get a list of all parents of a category in a array or in a List<int>.